# Using boto3 to get windows password

Tags: passwords, window, boto3

I am using boto3 to create an windows instance using a defined keypair.  Then I got stuck trying to decrypt the passworddata.

I am following the approach outline in the two post below:

https://gist.github.com/tinkerbotfoo/337df5bd1faff777fb52
https://quackajack.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/decrypting-aws-windows-passwords/

Approach 1 - returns a password but is incorrect

```
import rsa


# Get password data
ec2_cli = session.client('ec2')
response = ec2_cli.get_password_data(
    InstanceId='i-555555555555',
    DryRun=False
)
ciphertext = response['PasswordData']

key_path = 'my_private_key.pem'

passwd = base64.b64decode(ciphertext)
if (passwd):
    with open (key_path,'r') as privkeyfile:
    priv = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(privkeyfile.read())
rdp_pw = rsa.decrypt(passwd,priv)

print(rdp_pw)
```

Approach 2 - error during the call

```
key = RSA.importKey(input.read())
input.close()
from Crypto import Cipher
cipher = Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)

plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext, None)
print(plaintext)
```

This time I got the error
ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it.

```py
import boto3
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

def decrypt(key_text, password_data):
    key = RSA.importKey(key_text)
    cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
    return cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(password_data), None).decode('utf8')

private_key_file = '/path/to/your/key.pem'
region = 'us-east-1'
instance_id = your_instance_id

with open(private_key_file, 'r') as key_file:
    key_text = key_file.read()

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region)
response = ec2_client.get_password_data(InstanceId=instance_id)

print(decrypt(key_text, response['PasswordData']))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same `ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.` error.

Turns out my instance didn't have a password set because I launched it without a key/value pair. So, OP, be sure to check the value of `ec2_client.get_password_data(InstanceId=instance_id)` and try and connect to your Windows instance in the AWS web console first, just to be sure :)